# Detect when Facebook Like Button is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

As you probably know the Facebook Like button loads very slowly.

And I am trying to figure out how to detect when the button has finished loading and has been added to the website.

The reason being that I show a loading animation, and then hide that and show the button, but I'd like to show the button when it has finished loading.

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: As far as I am aware, the Facebook "Like" button processes your page after your page has finished loading all elements. It might be better to first profile your page to see what is taking the longest to load (probably images). I use: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: @Codesleuth my website doesn't have many images and loads within a second. I just wait for the facebook like button to load. Even if it starts loading once load is complete, how do i detect it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One can [subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to the xfbml.render event to get notified when rendering is complete, which only fires once per page parsing (and works not only for xfbml, but for the new html5 trickery too). Page parsing automatically happens when the FB JS SDK loads if `xfbml : true`.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    ...
    xfbml : true
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function(response) {
      alert('OMG... All Facebook sociaal plugins on page rendereed.... finally!');
  });
};

// And load the SDK Asynchronously here
```

Comment: Just FYI: XFBML and “the new html5 trickery” are in fact the same thing. The DIV-elements with the appropriate class and data-whatever attributes are just what FB call the “HTML5-compatible way of writing XFBML tags”.

Comment: Could anyone walk me through exactly where in the Facebook code I need to insert this part?

Comment: Have in mind that this doesn't take into account if the actual iframe, FB plugin uses, has loaded yet. So you can't say if your layout is updated or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the facebook Like button is wrapped in an iFrame. If it is, you can find something to reference that iFrame by and use ->

```
$('iframe[class/id/name=whatever]').load(function(){ 
  //This element is loaded 
});
```

**EDIT**

Based on your specific needs, we can hook into any attribute as mentioned in my comment, I simply choose `frameborder="0"` to hook into.

```
$('iframe[frameborder=0]').load(function(){
  alert("loaded.");
});
```

Comment: It is an `iframe`, but that `iframe` is inserted by a script (e.g. `//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js`) and in my experience it's the script's work that takes time, not creating the `iframe` and showing content - that part is actually very quick. Perhaps the OP can describe his symptoms more. In any case, your answer will solve his problem. NOTE: use `$('iframe.fb_ltr')` since this is the class my pages have.

Comment: In regards to the code I have found that the id is generated randomly so I don't know how to catch that, and it doesn't have a class. I have tried .fb_ltr instead of id and the function doesn't fire. Any ideas? THanks for your help!

Comment: What other attributes does the iframe have, does it have a name? height? width? anything? we can hook into any attribute it has and filter the selector based on that.

Comment: I've tried that there is a div class called 'fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget' and I did a hook as follows: '$('.fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget iframe')' and it still doesn't fire? Sorry if im doing something wrong!

Comment: I'm taking a look at the site that I use, I have a like button as well. My markup looks like `<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:65px;" src="..clipped"></iframe>` Does this look like yours?

Comment: To confirm, this code goes into the document.ready right? Because the function still isn't firing :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13225/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-cristian)

Comment: _“and in my experience it's the script's work that takes time, not creating the iframe and showing content”_ – I disagree; parsing XFBML and creating the iframe is usually so quick, it’s barely even noticeable. But what takes time is the HTTP request to Facebook’s servers to load the iframe’s _content_.

Comment: @Kalmi's solution of incorporating Facebook's event subscription is more elegant and less susceptible to future updates in FB's load strategy.

Comment: Although, this solution would be quite awesome. If this actually fires upon the iframe load, we can use it for all those nasty little social sharing buttons. Has it worked for you guys? I don't see any replies that say it does.

Comment: @Vik This was 2 years and ago and is no longer a viable solution :). it would be best to stick to the FB render event as identified above at this point.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding the Facebook widget dynamically and thus calling [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) manually, then you can you simply specify a callback function that gets called when rendering is complete.