# Make Facebook and Google+ buttons load simultaneously

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, google-plus, google-plus-one

Is there a way to make the "like" and the "+1" buttons load simultaneously.  If you press 'Run' on jsfiddle, you will see that not only Google+ loads noticeably earlier than Facebook, but the Google+ button is also jerked to the left and then to the right after the Facebook button is loaded.

It ruins the aesthetics of the site.  What are some of the methods people have tackled this issue?  By the way, I realize that < center> is deprecated--it's used here to demonstrate the problem more easily.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sh7aA/

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>window.fbAsyncInit=function(){FB.init({appId:'128762500483273',status:true,cookie:true,xfbml:true});};(function(){var e=document.createElement('script');e.type='text/javascript';e.src=document.location.protocol+'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';e.async=true;document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);}());</script>


<p style="text-align:center">Follow us!</p>
<center>
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

</center>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by SimonPlus, you could hide container with buttons and show it when buttons are ready. But I think is need to watch loading of each button because there is no warranty that google plus's button always will be loaded earlier.

Unfortunately, GooglePlus Button API hasn't the load event so it need to listen button's `iframe` load event. Facebook provide `xfbml.render` event and we can listen to it. Then we call callback and when both buttons are ready we may show their container.

I've created [demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/Sh7aA/6/) with example of this approach. I use `jQuery` for asynchronously load button scripts and subscribe to load event when buttons has begin to create.

Comment: Boris, that looks fantastic.  Two questions 1) I am not experienced with jquery.  Do I save that code as a separate file or include it somewhere on the page with a < script> or another tag?  2) Is there a way to load the "Follow us!" paragraph together with the buttons?

Comment: Also, how do I reserve the white space for the buttons so that it is not contracted/expanded while the hidden div is loading?  This is in order to prevent content below the div to move up/down.  See new jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Sh7aA/7/

Comment: Knocks,
1) you may include this script as you want, for example, in inline `script` tag

Comment: 2) If you want show "follow us" paragraph when buttons are ready, you need to wrap all buttons and paragraph into one block and call him to show

Comment: 3) For reserving space for buttons you need to know their height, but it unknown before it load. If you want, you may add another wrapper with hard-code height but it is out of subject of this question

Comment: Thanks!  This is the solution we chose to reserve space: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007982/reserve-white-space-while-hidden-div-is-loading

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the container containing the buttons and show it after they both have loaded. Since the Facebook button loads slower, you can [detect when it has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262914/detect-when-facebook-like-button-is-loaded) and then show the container.

Comment: Doesn't subscribing, listening, and detecting add extra code and processing time to the site?  What do you think of a solution that would contain both the Facebook and Google+ buttons in one div and just show it, say 3 seconds after the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

It's not "Pretty", but have you tried setting static widths for each of the divs? It will prevent the jerking around of the buttons.

Other methods I've seen used are replacing the buttons with images and then running the button load actions when the mouse hovers over the buttons.

Comment: I actually really like the solution by just-boris.  Just can't figure out where to stick that jquery code!