# Reserve white space while hidden div is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In the code below, a div is hidden until it gets OK from a 3rd-party server, and then it's rendered via jquery.  The purpose is to create an impression of smooth loading.  The problem is that the paragraph below this div is pushed down after the div is loaded, which defeats the purpose of the trick.  What's the best way to fix that?

http://jsfiddle.net/Sh7aA/7/

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<p style="text-align:center">Follow us!</p>
<center style="display: none;" id="social">
    <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
</center>

<p style="text-align:center">Test paragraph of text<br>
Paragarph continued</p>
```

Comment: replace `display:none` with `visibility:hidden`, that makes the element stay in the flow.

Comment: @adeneo that only helps if there is already content in the div that is about the same length as the content to be loaded

Comment: As a side note, `<center>` is depreciated! Don't use it!

Comment: @yochannah - doesn't matter what you do as long as the element is display none, you can set height, min-height and whatever up the wazzoo, but it won't help it the element isn't there.

Comment: @adeneo The facebook button fails to render when display:none is changed to visibility:hidden

Comment: @KnocksX - I know, tested it, this is the solution I came up with it -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Sh7aA/9/**

Comment: @adeneo.  It's beautiful.  Feel free to write it up as the correct answer. :)

Comment: Thanks, added it as an answer, as that seems to be the only reliable way to get the buttons loaded while still being invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the element a size, and set it's opacity to zero so the content is invisible

```
#social {opacity: 0; height: 25px; width: 100%; position: relative;}
```

Then animate in the content

```
$('#social').animate({opacity : 1}, 1000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sh7aA/9/)

Comment: I hate to dig this back up, but using this technique apparently hides the buttons from visitors who have Ad Block installed.  What exactly does Ad Block dislike about this animation, and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 5):

Set a `min-height` of the container where the content is loaded to match the height of the loaded content.

Comment: min-height did not seem to help